# R: sub setting a column based on two columns

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe called `mat.new`. Here's how to generate this data:

```
      library(dplyr)

      year <- rep(1980:2015, each = 365) 
      doy <- rep(1:365, times = 36)

      set.seed(125) 
      val <- sample(0:1, size = 365*36,replace = TRUE) 
      mat <- as.matrix(cbind(year,doy,val))
      mat <- as.data.frame(mat)
      mat <- mat %>% 
              mutate(doy1 = rep(1:730, times = 18))
      mat <- mat[,c(1:2,4,3)]

      set.seed(123) 
      mat1 <- apply(matrix(sample(c(230:365), replace = TRUE, size = 2L * 36L), nrow = 36L), 2L, sort)
      mat1 <- t(apply(mat1, 1, function(x) x[order(x)]))
      colnames(mat1) <- c("D1", "D2")
      mat1 <- cbind(year = 1980:2015, mat1)
      mat1 <- as.data.frame(mat1)

      mat1[1:6,3] <- 5:10

      mat1 <- mat1 %>%
                mutate(D2 = ifelse(D1 > D2, D2 + 365, D2))

      mat_new <- mat %>% 
                 left_join(mat1, by = "year")
```

`mat_new` has six columns. Column 1 = year, Column 2: `doy` (365 days each year), column 3 = `doy1` but goes from 1 till 730 ( 2 years) and repeats again from 1 to 730. Column 4 has some value (`val`), column 5 and 6 has a certain start (`D1`) and end doy (`D2`) of each year. If `D2` > 365, this implies the end date was next year. For e.g. for 1980, the end date is 370 which is the 5th day of 1981,

I need to subset `val` for each year based on their respective start and end doy. For e.g for 1980, the `val` I need to subset should start from 233 of 1980 till 5th of 1981 (370 is the end date). I thought of first creating another column with true and false which I can then use to subet the `val`

```
      mat_new1 <- mat_new %>% 
                    mutate(group1 = ifelse(D2 <= 365, doy >= D1 & doy <= D2 , doy >= D1 & doy1 <= D2))
```

The above line should create another column `group1` with TRUE and FALSE. If `D2` <= 365 i.e. the end date falls within the same year, use the `doy` column to subset `D1` till `D2`. However, if `D2` is
in the next year (D2 > 365), then use `doy` as start date and take the end date from `doy1` column. The above function, however for 1980 (and other years)
only puts TRUE starting the `D1` but ends at 365 for 1980 instead of going to 5th Jan of 1981 (370 from `doy1`)

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option. The idea is to filter the data frame for days in the same year and then the days in the next year based on `D1` and `D2`. To do this, `D2` is adjusted to count how many days are in the next year, so two look-up tables are needed for this approach. `mat_new3` is the final output.

By the way, some years are leap year so they have 366 days. It seems that you are assuming all years have 365 days. Just want to make sure you are aware of that and this does not affect your analysis.

```
# Look-up table for the same year
mat_day <- mat_new %>% 
  select(year, D1, D2) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  # Create a column D_next to show how many days are in the next year
  # After that, update D2 to only ended in 365 if D_next > 365
  mutate(D_next = ifelse(D2 > 365, D2 - 365, 0),
         D2 = D2 - D_next)

# Look-up table for the next year
mat_day_next <- mat_day %>%
  # Update the year column to represent the next year
  mutate(year = year + 1) %>%
  # Remove year if it is larger than the maximum of the original year
  filter(year <= max(mat_day$year)) %>%
  # Remove D_next == 0
  filter(D_next != 0) %>%
  # Remove D1 and D2
  select(-D1, -D2) %>%
  # Create a column showing the beginning day of the next year
  mutate(D1 = 1, D2 = D_next)

# Filter rows for the same year  
mat_new1 <- mat_new %>%
  # Join with may_day by year
  left_join(mat_day, by = c("year")) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  # Filter by D1.y and D2.y (D1 and D2 from mat_day)
  filter(doy >= D1.y & doy <= D2.y) %>%
  ungroup()

# Filter rows for the next year
mat_new2 <- mat_new %>%
  # Join with may_day_next by year
  left_join(mat_day_next, by = c("year")) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  # Filter by D1.y and D2.y (D1 and D2 from mat_day_next)
  filter(doy >= D1.y & doy <= D2.y) %>%
  ungroup()

# Combine the results 
mat_new3 <- bind_rows(mat_new1, mat_new2) %>%
  arrange(year, doy, doy1) %>%
  select(-D1.y, -D2.y, -D_next) %>%
  rename(D1 = D1.x, D2 = D2.x) %>%
  ungroup()

# View the first 6 rows from the year 1980
mat_new3 %>% head()
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#    year   doy  doy1   val    D1    D2
#   <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1  1980   233   233     0   233   370
# 2  1980   234   234     1   233   370
# 3  1980   235   235     0   233   370
# 4  1980   236   236     0   233   370
# 5  1980   237   237     0   233   370
# 6  1980   238   238     1   233   370

# View the last 10 rows from the year 1980
mat_new3 %>%
  slice(1:(370 - 233 + 1)) %>%
  tail(10)
# # A tibble: 10 x 6
#     year   doy  doy1   val    D1    D2
#    <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#  1  1980   361   361     0   233   370
#  2  1980   362   362     1   233   370
#  3  1980   363   363     0   233   370
#  4  1980   364   364     0   233   370
#  5  1980   365   365     1   233   370
#  6  1981     1   366     0   235   371
#  7  1981     2   367     1   235   371
#  8  1981     3   368     0   235   371
#  9  1981     4   369     1   235   371
# 10  1981     5   370     0   235   371
```